# How to modify maximum z render on Away3d?

Tags: flash, 3d, camera, render, away3d

I am using Away3d version 4.2 to render 3d objects on flash and I am not able to find a way to set the camera in order to render objects further than 2048 away from the camera on any axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.far` property of the camera lens allow to render larger dimensions